# Can browser-based mobile applications detect incoming phone numbers?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, blackberry

Theoretically, would it be possible to write a web browser-based mobile application (i.e. not a native app) that would detect the phone number of an incoming call and check that phone number against a database?  It would only need to run on recent versions of BlackBerry, iPhone, and Android phone browsers.  Thank you.

Comment: Why is the question rated a "-2"?  Was it because it was considered a bad question?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not exposed to the browser nor should it.

Comment: 'nor should it' - please explain

Comment: A phones browser should not have access to this information from a security and privacy point of view. If it was allowed to do this kind of action then every website could get your phone number and you wouldn't know.  It would be similar to a browser being able to get your email address, without you typing it in and giving it up on purpose. Sure you can safe guard yourself by being able to turn such a feature off, but most people do not do this and it would leave them exposed to fraud.

Comment: Do you not need to distinguish between the phones browser and the OPs web browser-based mobile application, and also consider (though the OP didn't mention them) the cross-platform packaging tools for 'web browser-based mobile applications' such as PhoneGap and RhoMobile et al, which include APIs for accessing device-side functionality. Rather than a straight No.

Comment: The question was about the browser having access to the phone number on a mobile device and the answer is a no, and it should not be an expected feature because of privacy issues. You can tell between a mobile browser and a regular browser through other ways other than reading a phone number.  The OP's question was about reading a phone number of a incoming call on a mobile device from the browser, and this is not exposed by a mobile browser currently nor should it ever be exposed in a mobile browser.

Comment: Now you've re-phrased the OPs question to fit your answer, neat.

Comment: "Theoretically, would it be possible to write a web browser-based mobile application (i.e. not a native app) that would detect the phone number of an incoming call and check that phone number against a database?" Ok, fine it would be possible yes, but it is not possible now (because this is not exposed to the browser) nor should it be allowed. I have answered the OP's question and stated that it shouldn't be allowed albeit without a long explanation why, as the reasons are quite obvious (security and privacy).